# Option for "I'm not looking for new job"

Tags: feature-request, jobs, options

I would like to my CV on careers, but I'm not looking for new job, now. But in future I would like change my current employer.

Answer (score 7):

Create your CV and don't publish it.  It's not publicly viewable until it's published.

Answer (score 4):

If your CV is searchable, you have this line on your status page:

> Your CV is searchable by employers; **hide from searches**

Just hide your CV from searches and employers won't find your CV. You can also unpublish it if you don't want anyone to see it at your public CV url.

Comment: +1 If you've filed your CV you can hide it from searches. But I have to say it was confusing at first because "filing" at first doesn't make it very clear that a CV can be hidden from searches until you've filed the CV.

Answer (score 1):

There are five checkboxes at the bottom of your CV listing the options:

> What type of work are you seeking?
>
> [] Full time permanent
> [] Temporary contract
> [] Telecommute
> [] I'm open to ideas
> [] Internship or Co-op

Just make sure all of them are cleared.

Answer (score 0):

**quote from FAQ**

> It is 100% free to create, edit, and
>   publish your professional programming
>   CV here.
>
> If you are seeking employment, we do
>   require a modest annual payment to
>   file your CV. Filing your CV makes it
>   eligible to appear in searches by
>   hiring managers via our private search
>   interface.